# sed command on single line input

Tags: linux, sed, solaris

I am using SunOS 10. I am trying to replace the `:` character at the end of line if the word contains `:` in it.

I am using the below command for it.

```
echo -n "test:" | sed 's/:$//g'
```

It's not working. What did I do wrong here?

The same command is working fine in GNU/Linux.

Comment: What sed version are you using?

Comment: Its Solaris 10 and the command is SunOS 5.10 (from the man page).

Comment: The `/g` flag is superfluous; you can obviously only replace the last individual character once.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a line feed. You need to remove that `-n`

```
echo "test:" | sed 's/:$//g'
```

Comment: Guessing this is correct, in the sense that the missing line terminator may mean that your `sed` does not see and end of line character. If you don't want a trailing newline, a workaround could be to add a pipe to `tr -d '\012'` (assuming SunOS `tr` accepts this notation for newline; consult its manual page if not).

Comment: Many Unix line-oriented utilities do not deal well with the last line of a file if it doesn't end in newline. Some versions of sed may be like this.

Comment: @Barmar Right, this applies to files because POSIX specifies that each file has to end with a newline. But maybe it also applies to many stdin input handlers as they are the same for stdin and files.

Comment: To be precise, it says that a "text file" has to end with a newline; binary files obviously don't. And then utilities specify whether their input is required to be text files; if so, it applies whether they're reading from an explicit filename or stdin. The programmer would usually have to go out of their way to have different requirements for one versus the other.

Answer (score 1):

```
myshell:/home/myfolderpath # echo -n "test:"|sed 's/:$//g'
testmyshell:/home/myfolderpath#
```

you code works on my machine.

because there is no tailing new line.you gonna see the result right before your next shell command line. -n is not necessary.

```
myshell:/home/myfolderpath # echo "test:"|sed 's/:$//g'
test
myshell:/home/myfolderpath#
```

it should be like this without -n